# /Drupal/ Stopped working

Tags: 7

I'm running a apache2 server on Ubuntu. While I was in the middle of configuring new content on my local instance of drupal via Firefox, the site suddenly stopped working. My first thought was the the apache2 server was down, so I restarted it. Then I created an index.html, and index.php that both worked (outside the drupal directory).

Now let's say I go to localhost/drupal/ I get a blank page. However, if I go to localhost/drupal/update.php I get the update page. I found that out as I was trying to figure out if any page would load. /index.php does not work.

Any idea to what I should investigate next? What's weird is that I was in the middle of working on the site when it went down. I don't see a reason for that to happen.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

**Update:** I found that apache log can be handy.
By typing into the terminal:sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log

I found that the log had the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class QueryConditionInterface in /var/www/html/drupal/includes/database/query.inc on line 16
```

I tried replacing this file with the file from the original drupal package, didn't work. Nor should it have because I didn't change any code in this file.

**Things I've tried:**

- Restart mysql and appache2 using `sudo service mysql restart`
- Delete /drupal/includes/ and re-populate it with files from the original

  package.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it can't connect to the database any more if it's crashing on /query.inc

Some things to try:

- Check your database daemon is running (`sudo service mysql status` or similar)
- Check that your settings file has the correct db information and permissions
- Check that your drupal *user* in mysql has right level of permissions (and that it exists)

Comment: - mysql is running
- settings file in ~/var/www/html/drupal/sites/default/settings.php are correct
- the drupal user exists and has the permission

I was in the middle of creating contents on the site, while it went down. That's why it doesn't make sense. It was working until it randomly stop.

Comment: Try restarting mysql, maybe a table is locked.

Comment: I agree that is seems mighty strange

Comment: restarted apache and mysql using
      `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: Hm, ok maybe have a look at [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1835480) and [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1833466)

Comment: Couldn't find anything to go on in those.
I just deleted everything under /drupal/ except sites. Now I'm getting the following error in the apache log  
`PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/drupal/includes/DETELE/database/select.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3179`

Comment: It's still finding the files you 'deleted'.  you'll have to move them out of your drupal install.
I suggest downloading a fresh install of drupal, putting your sites folder in it, and setting a symlink so that you can switch apache between them easily.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all files, and dropped the database, then re-did the site.
The problem was probably because I mixed and matches between an installation profile and the original package files.